# XML, XSD, cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

On unmarshalling event like "2:31. cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ns:users'." occurs

Users.java

```
    @XmlRootElement(namespace = "com.data")
public class Users {
    @XmlElement(name = "user")
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
.
.
```

User.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"first",  "last", "passes"})
public class User {
    private String first;
    private String last;
    @XmlElement(name = "pass")
    private String[] passes;
.
```

Accounts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns:users xmlns:ns="com.data">
    <user>
        <first>John</first>
        <last>Dou</last>
        <pass>10223544</pass>
    </user>
     <user>
        <first>Leroy</first>
        <last>Jenkins</last>
        <pass>dQ112aDf</pass>
    </user>
</ns:users>
```

Validation.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="users">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="user"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="user">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="first"/>
                <xs:element name="last"/>
                <xs:element name="pass" maxOccurs="2"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Note: if possible xml file with data 'Accounts' shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is in the namespace `com.data`, but your schema does not declare elements in that namespace.

Add `targetNamespace="com.data"` to your xs:schema element.